# не могу установить sass через npm

Tags: node.js, gulp, npm, sass

Не могу установить sass через Npm
Вводя npm i gulp-sass --save-dev получаю ошибку:

'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! errno 1

npm ERR! node-sass@4.14.1 install: `node scripts/install.js`

npm ERR! Exit status 1

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.14.1 install script.

npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

Comment: пишут, что надо установить node.js или настроить кое-что в путях https://stackoverflow.com/a/28821955/4496422

Comment: nodejs установлен и путь в path добавлен

Comment: windows? я видел, вы используете git bash, что выводит команда `which node` и `node -v`?

Comment: @nörbörnën windows, да. `$ which node` /c/Program Files/nodejs/node и `$ node -v` v14.15.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

команда сработала с простого cmd. проблема была в git bash